# function not returning value. Error "NameError: name 'urlss' is not defined"

Tags: python

This is a part of my program. It gives the error `NameError: name 'urlss' is not defined`

```
def testfunc():
  urlss = "hey"
  return urlss

print urlss
```

Why does this occur?

Answer (score 9):

`urlss` is a variable local to the scope of `testfunc()`; it cannot be accessed elsewhere. You might mean

```
print testfunc()
```

which in this case prints `urlss`, since that's what `testfunc()` returns.

Comment: or if you need the variable later, use urlss = testfunc()

Comment: WHat if i want to store the value of urlss outside the function?

Comment: @user2675742 As AliBZ suggests, you can assign what the function returns to a new variable: `urlss = testfunc()`.